# how to retrieve values from existing table using hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am using **Hibernate & Spring** In my project. I need to access already existing table values from DB using hibernate.

I just have an **entity** class & I use Constructor injection here.
I am Using **Hibernate & spring** in same file.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate allows to generate beans and mapping configuration out of existing databases. This is called `Reverse Engineering'.

You can find the documentation here:

http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/reverseengineering.html